# Subsetting data.table based on repeated rows

Tags: r, data.table, row, subset

I have a list of data tables stored in an object `ddf` (a sample is shown below):

```
 [[43]]
    V1 V2 V3
1:  b  c  a
2:  b  c  a
3:  b  c  a
4:  b  c  a
5:  b  b  a
6:  b  c  a
7:  b  c  a

 [[44]]
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  c  a
2:  a  c  a
3:  a  c  a
4:  a  c  a
5:  a  c  a

 [[45]]
   V1 V2 V3
1:  a  c  b
2:  a  c  b
3:  a  c  b
4:  a  c  b
5:  a  c  b
6:  a  c  b
7:  a  c  b
8:  a  c  b
9:  a  c  b
               .............and so on till [[100]]
```

I want to Subset the list `ddf` such that the result only consists of ddf's which:

1. have at least 9 rows each
2. each of the 9 rows are same
3. I want to store this sub-setted output

I have written some code for this below:

```
 for(i in 1:100){
 m=(as.numeric(nrow(df[[i]]))>= 9)
 if(m == TRUE & df[[i]][1,] = df[[i]][2,] = 
 =df[[i]][3,] =df[[i]][4,] =df[[i]][5,] =df[[i]][6,]=
 df[[i]][7,]=df[[i]][8,]=df[[i]][9,]){
 print(df[[i]])
 }}
```

Please tell me whats wrong & how I can generalize the result for sub-setting based on "n" similar rows.

[Follow-up Question]

```
    Answer obtained from Main question:
    > ddf[sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(x) >= n & nrow(unique(x)) == 1)]
      $`61`
         V1 V2 V3
      1:  a  c  b
      2:  a  c  b
      3:  a  c  b
      4:  a  c  b
      5:  a  c  b
      6:  a  c  b
      7:  a  c  b

      $`68`
         V1 V2 V3
      1:  a  c  a
      2:  a  c  a
      3:  a  c  a
      4:  a  c  a
      5:  a  c  a
      6:  a  c  a
      7:  a  c  a
      8:  a  c  a

      $`91`
         V1 V2 V3
      1:  b  c  a
      2:  b  c  a
      3:  b  c  a
      4:  b  c  a
      5:  b  c  a
      6:  b  c  a
      7:  b  c  a

               ..... till the last data.frame which meet the row matching criteria (of at least 9 similar rows)

      There are only 2 types of elements in the list: 
                  **[[.. ]]**        
     **Case 1.** >70% accuracy       
     **Case 2.** <70% accuracy
```

You will notice that the Output shown above in the "Follow Up Question" is for

$'61', $'68' & $'91', but there is NO output for the other dataframes which don't match the "matching row" criteria.

I need an output where these missing values which don't match the output criteria give an output of "bad output".

Thus the Final list should be the same length as the input list.

By placing them side-by-side using paste I should be able to see each output.

Comment: Please read the info on how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: Done. Is it better now?

Comment: Ideally, we would be able to copy/paste all of your code into R and start tinkering. The data you provide isn't all that suited for import. See the link Jaap provided on how to effortlessly share (simulated) data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through the `list` ('ddf'), subset only the `duplicate` rows with (`duplicated`), `order` the dataset, `if` the number of rows of the dataset 'x1' is greater than 8, then get the first 9 rows (`head(x1, 9)`) or `else` return 'bad result' printed

```
lapply(ddf, function(x) {
  x1 <- x[duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast=TRUE)]
if(nrow(x1)>9) {
 x1[order(V1, V2, V3), head(.SD, 9)] 

  } else "bad answer"
 })
#[[1]]
#   V1 V2 V3
#1:  b  c  a
#2:  b  c  a
#3:  b  c  a
#4:  b  c  a
#5:  b  c  a
#6:  b  c  a
#7:  b  c  a
#8:  b  c  a
#9:  b  c  a

#[[2]]
#[1] "bad answer"

#[[3]]
#[1] "bad answer"
```

#### data

```
ddf <- list(data.table(V1 = 'b', V2 = rep(c('c', 'b', 'c'), c(8, 1, 2)), V3 = 'a'),
       data.table(V1 = rep("a", 5), V2 = rep("c", 5), V3 = rep("a", 5)),
       data.table(V1 = c('b', 'a', 'b', 'b'), V2 = c('b', 'a', 'c', 'b'),
       V3 = c("c", "d", "a", "b")))
```

Comment: I get a function error: 2nd argument must be a list

Comment: function (what, args, quote = FALSE, envir = parent.frame()) 
{
  if (!is.list(args)) 
    stop("second argument must be a list")
  if (quote) 
    args <- lapply(args, enquote)
  .Internal(do.call(what, args, envir))
}

Comment: @Rishi Corrected the problem

Comment: @arun I'm getting an incorrect answer for the subsetting, I am getting one data.table outputs when I should be getting two

Comment: @Rishi I added an example data in my post and is working fine with it

Comment: Yes @akrun Thank You

Comment: there is an issue: If the data has 2 sets of repeated values then I get an incorrect result.

Comment: @RishiTandon  My logic was that there would be many repeat values and it selects the first one after ordering.

Comment: How can I coerce this output: ddf[sapply(ddf, nrow) >= 9 & sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(unique(x))) == 1] with a loop :: for the errors I get "bad result"

Comment: @rtaero  I think your question should be directed towards the other answer which uses that code

Comment: the loop is more important for my case, please share a code for filtering the data.frame's in the list 'ddf' based on a minimum of "n" similar, unique rows.

Comment: @rtaero  I think what you may need is `lapply(ddf, function(x) if(nrow(x) >= n & nrow(unique(x)) == 1) x else "Bad output")`

Answer (score 2):

When `ddf` is your list of datatables, then:

```
ddf[sapply(ddf, nrow) >= 9 & sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(unique(x))) == 1]
```

should give you the desired result.

Where:

- `sapply(ddf, nrow) >= 9` checks whether the datatables have nine or more rows
- `sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(unique(x))) == 1` checks whether all the rows are the same.

Or with one `sapply` call as @docendodiscimus suggested:

```
ddf[sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(x) >= 9 & nrow(unique(x)) == 1)]
```

Or by using the `.N` special symbol and the `uniqueN` function of `data.table`:

```
ddf[sapply(ddf, function(x) x[,.N] >= 9 & uniqueN(x) == 1)]
```

Another option is to use `Filter` (following the suggestion of @Frank in the comments):

```
Filter(function(x) nrow(x) >= 9 & uniqueN(x) == 1, ddf)
```

---

Two approaches to get the datatable numbers:

**1.** Using `which`:

```
which(sapply(ddf, function(x) nrow(x) >= 9 & nrow(unique(x)) == 1))
```

**2.** Assign names to the datatables in the list:

```
names(ddf) <- paste0('dt', 1:length(ddf))
```

now the output will have the datatable number in the output:

```
$dt4
  V1 V2 V3
1  a  c  b
2  a  c  b
3  a  c  b
4  a  c  b
5  a  c  b
6  a  c  b
7  a  c  b
8  a  c  b
9  a  c  b
```

Comment: Can't you do both check in one `sapply` call?

Comment: @Jaap - I need the datatable number to appear in the output .. e.g. lst[[11]] ..., lst[[15]], assuming they meet the criteria of subsetting

Comment: @Jaap - I need an output as a list :: for an inaccurate result I get "< 70% accuracy". For the correct output I get the datatable. This may need a for-loop

Comment: @rtaero The methods I showed are returning a list and giving the correct output. Please explain your problem in more detail. You could do that by adding an extra section to your question where you explain this.

Comment: @Jaap I have added "[Follow-up Question]" in the main Question, for the benefit of the community

Comment: @rtaero please [see here for instructions on how to make the question reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610) (now it isn't); you could for example include the output of `dput(head(name_of_list))`

Comment: @Jaap Please help me answer this extended part of the question, have included changes to code based on suggestions

Comment: Sir, would really appreciate your help in this @Jaap, I have tried many combinations of loops and tried to run this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @rtaero for the output you need for the followup question, I think akrun already provided you with a good solution

Comment: Need to clarify the answer for the benefit of the community

Comment: @Azi Would you care to explain the downvote (since it came shortly after my last comment, I guess it was you)? At the beginning of my answer I've explained what the two parts do. If you think it could be improved, please explain how.